# Nlog: send mail when Loglevel >= Loglevel.Error with last x messages

Tags: nlog

I'd like to do this (from log4net [docu](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html)) with nlog:

This example shows how to deliver only significant events. A LevelEvaluator is specified with a threshold of WARN. This means that an email will be sent for each WARN or higher level message that is logged. Each email will also contain up to 512 (BufferSize) previous messages of any level to provide context. Messages not sent will be discarded.

**Is it possible?**

I only found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/167846/NLog-email-buffering-wrapper) on codeproject.
But it uses a wrapper target that flushes in behalf of the number of messages, not on the log level.

Thanks
Tobi

Comment: This is a great question and I am surprised that such a great tool like NLog doesn't have this option. I guess that customizing BufferingTargetWrapper.cs would do the trick. Did you solve this issue in the end?

Answer (score 1):

There is a  [QueuedTargetWrapper](https://github.com/MikeJansen/NLog/commit/2b71ba626ae043f6e6ecc146efacbe6ae3f5e0d2)    (   a target that buffers log events and sends them in batches to the wrapped target)
 that seems address the requirement. I haven't tried it yet.

There is a related discussion "[The Benefits of Trace Level Logging in Production Without the Drawback of Enormous Files](https://github.com/jkowalski/NLog/pull/14)"

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution that will write last 200 log-events on error:

```
  <target name="String" xsi:type="AutoFlushWrapper" condition="level >= LogLevel.Error" flushOnConditionOnly="true">
     <target xsi:type="BufferingWrapper"
          bufferSize="200"
          overflowAction="Discard">
        <target xsi:type="wrappedTargetType" ...target properties... />
     </target>
  </target>
```

See also: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/BufferingWrapper-target